# EPPlus producing an empty Excel file after SaveAs

Tags: c#, epplus-4

I'm using the latest 4.5.3.3 nuget version. .NET 4.6.1.

No issues if I create an excel file from scratch, but if I need to update an existing one, even if passing it to the ExcelPackage ctor and calling a ExcelPackage.Save after updating the data, or create a copy of the original excel file to pass to ExcelPackage ctor I obtain the same result.

```
        FileInfo exc = new FileInfo(destPath);

        using (var ep = new ExcelPackage(exc))
        {
            foreach (var sheet in _resultTranslations.Keys)
            {
                List<string> sheetTrs = _resultTranslations[sheet];

                var ws = ep.Workbook.Worksheets[sheet];

                if (ws == null)
                    continue;

                for (int r = 0; r < sheetTrs.Count; r++)
                {
                    ws.Cells[2 + r, 6].Value = sheetTrs[r];
                }
            }

            ep.Save();
        }
```

UPDATE:
If I open the Excel file with Office 2016, and save it without any changes, EEPlus updates it correctly (it's no more blank).

Any suggestion?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try `Save` instead of `SaveAs`? Just  `ep.Save();`

Comment: Yes, in the first attempt I used it, instead of making a copy of the original file. The strange think is that the result file size is almost the same of the original, but all cells are white.

Comment: So you can update file then, but all cells are white?

Comment: Exactly. The two sheets are there but "apparently" empty (since the file size seems to tell it's all ok). The original file is full text based, no formulas no graphics...only texts.

Is there an encoding setting somewhere?

Comment: I think it's because you  set String.Empty to value of cell.  `ws.Cells[2 + r, 6].Value = string.Empty;`? Could you change something like  `ws.Cells[2 + r, 6].Value = "value";` and try it again?

Comment: No, that was a test to see if it was the cell value assignment the issue.